# Getting rid of asymptotic notation in Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Let's suppose I want to resolve the following Recurrence Relation:
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n=1 \\
      T(n-1) + \Theta(n) & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

I want to prove that the following
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n=1 \\
      T(n-1) + cn & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
will be asymptotycally equivalent to the first Recurrence Relation.

This is how I approached the proof, but I am stuck, so I'd love to receive an help:

**Proof**
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n=1 \\
      T(n-1) + \Theta(n) & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
means
$$ T(n) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & n=1 \\
      T(n-1) + f(n) & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
where $f(n) \in \Theta(n)$.

This implies that $$\exists c_1 > 0, c_2>0, n_0>0 : c_1n \leq f(n) \leq c_2n, \ \forall n \geq n_0$$

Now let's sum $T(n-1)$:
$$T(n-1) + c_1n \leq T(n-1) + f(n) \leq T(n-1) + c_2n \ \forall n \geq n_0$$

$$\implies T(n-1) + c_1n \leq T(n) \leq T(n-1) + c_2n \ \forall n \geq n_0$$

So we have
$$T(n) \geq T(n-1)+c_1n\ \forall n \geq n_0$$
$$T(n) \leq T(n-1)+c_2n\ \forall n \geq n_0$$

I am close to the conclusion, but from now I cannot **formally** prove what I stated earlier. Thank you in advance.

Comment: But that's not true. The second relation has only one solution $T(n) = 1 + c \frac{n (n + 1)}{2} - c$, while the first has much more.

Comment: @mihaild, true, I wanted to prove that they are **asymptotically** equivalent (question edited)